# Which dimensions from Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse exist in other works?

Tags: marvel, spider-man, parallel-universe, continuity, spider-man-into-the-spider-verse

*Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse* features versions of Spider-Man from various parallel dimensions. Are all of these "new" dimensions, or are they intended to be existing-dimensions within the Marvel multiverse of comics, films, etc.? In other words, are any of the Spider-People we see from established Marvel universes (e.g. Earth-616, Earth-1610, Earth-199999, Amazing Spider-Man universe, etc.), or does this movie exist outside the continuity of any other Marvel storyline?

For example, is

> The older, divorced, somewhat overweight thirtysomething Peter Parker

supposed to represent a future Amazing Spider-Man, Marvel Cinematic Universe Spider-Man, or some other version of Spider-Man?

To be clear, I'm not asking about what works *inspired* this movie, I'm asking to what extent it exists *within* the continuity of those previous works, as opposed to just being inspired by it.

Comment: This is a great question, but I wish you'd also included the four named villains besides the alternate spidermen.  Some or all of those villains must have appearances in earlier media too.

Answer (score 11):

- Spider-Noir - *[Spider-man Noir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_Noir)*
- Peter-Porker - *[Spider-Ham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Ham)*
- Spider-Gwen - *[Spider-Man (Gwen Stacy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Woman_(Gwen_Stacy))*
- Peter B. Parker - *[Raimi universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_in_film#Sam_Raimi_films)* (it employs scenes from the films, as well as the scrapped plot for a fourth film that would have had Peter and M.J. divorce, although some aspects vary in the depiction such as webshooters)
- Peni Parker - *[Marvel Mangaverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(Marvel_Mangaverse))*
- Miles Morales - *[Ultimate Spider-man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miles_Morales)*

The stinger has appearances from:

> *[Spider-Man 2099](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_2099)* and [the Spider-Man from the 1967 cartoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(1967_TV_series)).

Comment: While Peter B. Parker did have some scenes out of the Raimi films, he had artificial web slingers - in the Raimi films, Spider-Man generated webs organically.

Comment: @RobertColumbia: I've amended my answer to include your comment. I could have sworn I saw a "from the director" comment about the source of the character, but I'm having no luck.

Comment: @Ynaught - I see that you've submitted an edit to this answer to correct what you see as a factual inaccuracy. Instead of editing someone else's answer though, I'd recommend posting what you believe to be the correct information within a separate answer of your own. That way, you're not altering the intent of someone else's post, and you give yourself the opportunity to earn some reputation.

Comment: @LogicDictates: They did post it 23 days ago. You were among the people who voted to delete it.

Comment: @Ynaught: FWIW, your prior answer, posted May 11, had some of these details, as well as some questions. The key is to write the details as an answer without the question in it, and, if you desire, putting those queries into your own question on the site, which others can contribute to.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - What this user posted before was more of a question than an answer. But with some reframing of the first paragraph, the removal of the second one, and the addition of the sources they've attempted to edit into your answer here, they certainly have enough now to write a decent answer to this question.

Comment: Incidentally, that second paragraph could be reframed into a decent question as well. But it absolutely should be posted as a question, not an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Most of the Spider-Man and Spider-Woman variants in the *Spider-Verse* films come from existing dimensions within the Marvel multiverse. In the sequel, *Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse* (2023), we can see the [designations of the existing universes that some of these Spider-People belong to](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/276148/7957).

For example, in *Across the Spider-Verse*, we see that Gwen Stacy / Spider-Gwen is from [Earth-65](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-65), Miguel O’Hara / Spider-Man 2099 is from [Earth-928](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-928), Spidercide is from [Earth-616](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-616) (the main comic book universe), and Tarantula is from the [Ultimate Marvel Universe, Earth-1610A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Marvel)*, which are all existing universes in the comics. It is likely that the same applies to [Peter Porker / Spider-Ham](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Porker_(Earth-8311)) (who is from [Larval Earth / Earth-8311](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-8311)), [Peni Parker / SP//dr](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peni_Parker_(Earth-14512)) ([Earth-14512](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-14512)), and [Spider-Man Noir](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-90214)) ([Marvel Noir / Earth-90214](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-90214)).

<sup>* The film uses "Earth-1610A" (with an "A") to differentiate Tarantula’s home universe from the universe of Miles Morales in the *Spider-Verse* films, which is [called Earth-1610](https://i.stack.imgur.com/af9Bq.jpg) in *Across the Spider-Verse*. In the comics, Miles Morales is originally from the Ultimate Marvel Universe.</sup>

*Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse* screencaps showing the universe designations:

[image: Earth-65, Spider-Gwen's world]

[image: Nueva York / Earth-928]

[image: Peter Parkedcar, Spidercide, Tarantula, Last Stand, and LEGO Spider-Man with their home universes labeled in Across the Spider-Verse]

[image: Mumbattan / Earth-50101]

In *Across the Spider-Verse*, [Peter B. Parker](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-616B))’s home universe is labeled “[Earth-616B](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-616B)”, a dimension that did not exist in the Marvel multiverse prior to *Into the Spider-Verse*. Adding a “B” to “Earth-616”, the main comic book universe, implies that he is based on Earth-616 Peter Parker.

Peter B. Parker and *Spider-Verse* Miles Morales belong to universes that *Into the Spider-Verse* introduced. Peter B. Parker is not the Tobey Maguire Spider-Man from the Sam Raimi film *Spider-Man* (2002), as [another answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/201684/7957) suggested, since that version of Spider-Man appears separately from Peter B. Parker in *Across the Spider-Verse*.

Screencaps of Gwen's interdimensional portal watch before traveling to Peter B. Parker's universe:

[image] [image]