# Who are all the different versions of Spider-Man, Spider-Woman and the alternate universe villains in "Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse"?

Tags: marvel, spider-man, spider-man-across-the-spider-verse

Who are all the different versions of Spider-Man, Spider-Woman and the alternate universe villains in *Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse*?

After seeing the movie yesterday afternoon, I was curious of who all the Multiverse characters were.

Comment: Found this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dy_VSOXGuNE

Answer (score 11):

#### Spider-Man and Spider-Woman variants

[**Gwen Stacy / Spider-Woman**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Woman_(Gwen_Stacy)) (returning from *Into the Spider-Verse* (2018); 2014 *Edge of Spider-Verse* Vol. 1 #2; Earth-65)

[**Miguel O'Hara / Spider-Man 2099**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_2099) (1992 *Spider-Man 2099* Vol. 1 #1; Earth-928)

[**Hobie Brown / Spider-Punk**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Punk) (2014 *Amazing Spider-Man* Vol. 3 #10; Earth-138)

[**Jessica Drew / Spider-Woman**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Woman_(Jessica_Drew))  (1976 *Marvel Spotlight* Vol. 1 #32; Earth-616)

[**Peter B. Parker / Spider-Man**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-TRN701)) (returning from *Into the Spider-Verse* (2018)), and his daughter, Mayday Parker.

[**Pavitr Prabhakar / Spider-Man India**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(Pavitr_Prabhakar)) (2004 *Spider-Man: India #1*; Earth-50101)

[**Margo Kess / Spider-Byte**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Byte_(Margo)_(Earth-22191)) (2018 *Vault of Spiders* Vol. 1 #1; Earth-22191)

[image: Margo Kess / Spider-Byte][image: Margo Kess / Spider-Byte]

[**Ben Reilly / Scarlet Spider**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_Reilly) (1994 *Spider-Man* Vol. 1 #52; part of the [1994 Clone Saga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_Saga) storyline; the version that appeared in the film is the [Earth-94](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-94) version "In this reality, Ben Reilly didn't die at the hands of the Green Goblin, and kept being Spider-Man […]")

[image: Ben Reilly / Scarlet Spider]

**Spider-Man** from [***The Spectacular Spider-Man***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spectacular_Spider-Man_(TV_series)) (2008 animated TV series; Earth-26496)

[image: The Spectacular Spider-Man*]

"**Insomniac Spider-Man**" from [*Marvel's Spider-Man*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(2018_video_game)) (2018 video game developed by Insomniac Games; Earth-1048)

[image: Insomniac Spider-Man*]

[**Patrick O'Hara / Web-Slinger**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Patrick_O%27Hara_(Earth-31913)), and his horse, **Widow** (2014 *Amazing Spider-Man* Vol. 3 #9; Earth-31913)

[image: Patrick O'Hara / Web-Slinger] [image: Patrick O'Hara / Web-Slinger]

[**Charlotte Webber / Sun-Spider**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Charlotte_Webber_(Earth-20023)) (2019 *Spider-Verse* Vol. 3 #3; Earth-20023)

[image: Charlotte Webber / Sun-Spider] [image: Charlotte Webber / Sun-Spider]

[**Malala Windsor / Spider-UK**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Malala_Windsor_(Earth-835)) (Earth-835)

[image: Malala Windsor / Spider-UK] [image: Malala Windsor / Spider-UK]

[**Max Borne / Spider-Man 2211**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Max_Borne_(Earth-9500)) (1995 *Spider-Man 2099 Meets Spider-Man* #1; Earth-9500)

[image: Max Borne / Spider-Man 2211]

[**Spidercide**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spidercide_(Earth-616)) (1995 *Amazing Spider-Man* Vol. 1 #399; part of the [1994 Clone Saga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_Saga) storyline; Earth-616)

[**"Last Stand" Spider-Man**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-312500)) (2003 *Amazing Spider-Man* Vol. 2 #58; Earth-312500)

[**Tarantula**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Tarantula_(Earth-1610)) (2006 Ultimate Spider-Man Clone Saga; Ultimate Marvel universe / Earth-1610A)

<sup>Note: The film uses "Earth-1610A" (with an "A") to differentiate Tarantula’s home universe from the universe of Miles Morales in the *Spider-Verse* films, which is [called Earth-1610](https://i.stack.imgur.com/af9Bq.jpg) in *Across the Spider-Verse*. In the comics, both Tarantula and Miles Morales are originally from the Ultimate Marvel Universe, which is also designated "Earth-1610" in the comics.</sup>

**[Peter Parkedcar / Spider-Mobile](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parkedcar_(Earth-53931))** (2015 *Amazing Spider-Man* Vol. 3 #12; Earth-53931)

[image: Peter Parkedcar, Spidercide, Tarantula, Last Stand, LEGO Spider-Man]

**[LEGO Spider-Man](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-13122))** (2012 *LEGO Marvel Super Heroe*s #5; Earth-13122)

[image: LEGO Spider-Man]

[**Spider-Cat**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Cat_(Earth-999)) (2011 *Spider-Island: I Love New York City* Vol. 1 #1; Earth-999)

[image: Spider-Cat*]

[**Maybelle Reilly / Lady Spider**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Maybelle_Reilly_(Earth-803)) (2014 *Spider-Verse* Vol. 1 #1; Earth-803)

[image: Maybelle Reilly / Lady Spider][image: Maybelle Reilly / Lady Spider]

**Spider-Man** from ***[Spider-Man: Unlimited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_Unlimited)*** (1999 animated TV series; Earth-751263)

[image: Spider-Man: Unlimited] [image: Spider-Man: Unlimited]

[**Spider-Man wearing Spider-Armor MK I**](https://spiderman.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Armor_MK_I) (1993 *Web of Spider-Man* Vol. 1 #100; Earth-616)

**Cyborg Spider-Woman** (introduced in the film)

[image: Cyborg Spider-Woman] [image: Cyborg Spider-Woman]

["**Werewolf Spider-Man**"](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-7085)) (2007 *Marvel Zombies/Army of Darkness* Vol. 1 #5; Earth-7085)

[image: Werewolf Spider-Man]

[**Spider-Man wearing Spider-Armor MK II**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Armor_MK_II) (2011 *Amazing Spider-Man* Vol. 1 #656; Earth-616)

[image: Spider-Armor MK II]

[**Mary Jane Watson-Parker / Spinneret**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Mary_Jane_Watson_(Earth-18119)) and [**Anna-May "Annie" Parker / Spiderling**](https://spiderman.fandom.com/wiki/Anna-May_Parker_(Earth-18119)) (2015 *Amazing Spider-Man: Renew Your Vows* Vol. 1 #1; Earth-18119)

[image]

[**Sir Peter Parker / Prince of Arachne**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-71004)) (2007 *Spider-Man: Fairy Tales* Vol. 1 #4; Earth-71004)

[image: Sir Peter Parker / Prince of Arachne]

[**Doppelganger**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Doppelganger_(Spider-Man)_(Earth-616)) (1992 *Infinity War* #1; Earth-616)

[image: Doppelganger]

[**"Ends of the Earth" Spider-Man**, wearing Spider-Armor MK III](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Armor_MK_III) (2012 *Amazing Spider-Man* Vol. 1 #682 "[Ends of the Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ends_of_the_Earth_(Marvel_Comics))" storyline; Earth-616)

[image: Ends of the Earth" Spider-Man]

[**"Bombastic Bag-Man"**](https://spiderman.fandom.com/wiki/Spare_Fantastic_Four_Costume) / Spider-Man wearing a paper bag as a mask ([1984 *Amazing Spider-Man* Vol. 1 #258](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_258); Earth-616)

[image: Bombastic Bag-Man]

**[Peter Ptarker / Spider-Rex](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Pter_Ptarker_(Earth-66))** (2022 *Edge of Spider-Verse* Vol. 2 #1; Earth-66)

[image: Peter Ptarker / Spider-Rex] [image: Peter Ptarker / Spider-Rex] [image: Peter Ptarker / Spider-Rex]

[**Spider-Man (1967 animated TV series)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(1967_TV_series))

[image: 1960s cartoon Spider-Man]

**[Spider-Monkey](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-8101))** [(2008 Marvel Apes / Earth-8101)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Apes)

[image] [image]

**[Mangaverse Spider-Man](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-2301))** (2002 *Marvel Mangaverse: Spider-Man* #1)

[image] [image]

**[Spider-Cop](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Cop_(Earth-19119))** (2018 *Spider-Geddon*; Earth-19119)

[image: Spider-Cop]

[**Eugene "Flash" Thompson / Captain Spider**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Eugene_Thompson_(Earth-78127)) (1977 *What If?* Vol. 1 #7; Earth-78127)

[image: Eugene "Flash" Thompson / Captain Spider] [image: Eugene "Flash" Thompson / Captain Spider]]

[**Julia Carpenter / Spider-Woman**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_Carpenter) (1984 *Marvel Super Heroes Secret Wars* Vol. 1 #6; Earth-616)

[image: Julia Carpenter / Spider-Woman]

**[Anya Corazon / Araña / Spider-Girl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anya_Corazon)** (2004 *Amazing Fantasy* Vol. 2 #1; Earth-616)

<sup>([Confirmed by Kris Anka](https://web.archive.org/web/20230617001641/https://twitter.com/kristaferanka/status/1669063914074832896), lead character designer of *Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse*)</sup>

[image: Anya Corazon / Araña / Spider-Girl]

**Metro Spider-Man** (introduced in the film) — voiced by [Metro Boomin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_Boomin), who wrote music for the original soundtrack of *Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse*

[image: Metro Spider-Man]

**Peni Parker / SP//dr**

[image: Peni Parker / SP//dr] [image: Peni Parker / SP//dr]

**Spider-Man Noir**

**Peter Porker / Spider-Ham**

**Tobey Maguire Spider-Man** from *Spider-Man* (2002)

[image: Tobey Maguire Spider-Man from Spider-Man (2002)]

**Andrew Garfield Spider-Man** from *The Amazing Spider-Man* (2012)

[image: Andrew Garfield Spider-Man from *The Amazing Spider-Man]

#### Villains

**Adriano Tumino** / **Renaissance Vulture**

[image: Adriano Tumino / Renaissance Vulture] [image: Adriano Tumino / Renaissance Vulture]

[**Armadillo**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armadillo_(character))

[image: Armadillo]

[**Johnathon Ohnn** / **The Spot**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_(comics))

[**Mooseterio**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Mooseterio_(Earth-8311)) (Larval Earth / Earth-8311, the home universe of Spider-Ham)

[image: Mooseterio]

**Videoman** (1981 *Spider-Man and his Amazing Friends*)

**Green Goblin** (1982 *[Spider-Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(1982_video_game))* Atari video game)
<sub>Left to right: Videoman, Insomniac Spider-Man, and Green Goblin</sub>

[image: Videoman, Insomniac Spider-Man, and Green Goblin]

[**Typeface**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface_(comics)) (2000 *Peter Parker: Spider-Man* Vol. 2 #23)

[image: Typeface]

**Miles Morales / Earth-42 Prowler**

[image: Miles Morales / Earth-42 Prowler]